# How to use DropDown After using virtual binding in KnockOut?

Tags: knockout.js

Here i am using a virtual binding for hiding a dropdownlist .For a condition i will show the dropdowmlist.But i cant select the dropdownlist.

```
                      <!-- ko if: chartType -->
                        <select id="chartType">
                            <option>column</option>
                            <option>bar</option>
                        </select>
                      <!-- /ko -->
```

and my js:

`$("#li_tab2").live("click", function () {
        viewModel.chartType(true);
    });`

how can fix this issue please help me?

Comment: Does the droplist not appear?  You also don't have any bindings in your select element so knockout won't do anything when the select appears and you select an option

Comment: dropdownnlist appear but i cant select the list sir.

Comment: it will not work if you are using "If Binding" so better to use visible binding.

Comment: Is the select disabled.  When you click on the select list do any items appear.

Comment: @akhlesh, makes no difference.  Knockout will create the nodes when chartType becomes true

Comment: @akhlesh sir i also use if binding but no use

Comment: Sorry my mistake, btw which version of jquery and ko you are using?

Comment: @akhlesh  jQuery 1.10.2 and 2.0.3

Comment: for running the same code you have to use ko version 2.2.1 or greater.
you can check this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/vQc4e/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/vQc4e/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the value of the select box you need to add bindings to the select element

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: onShowChartType">Show Chart Type</button>
<!-- ko if: chartType -->
    <select id="chartType"  data-bind="
         options: chartTypes, 
         optionsCaption:'Please select...', 
         value: selectedChartType">
    </select>
<!-- /ko -->

<br />
<span>Selected chart type:</span>
<span data-bind="text: selectedChartType"></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = { 
    chartType: ko.observable(false),
    chartTypes: ko.observableArray(["column", "bar"]),
    selectedChartType: ko.observable(),
    onShowChartType: function() {
        this.chartType(true);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqZ8Q/)